# Is there a way to group options in Input in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using [react-select](https://react-select.com/home).

I need to group options in the input. The next values should be added to a specific group
just like it is in "MenuList" component with groups

[here what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNNrh.png)

https://prnt.sc/qybffp

**Ideas on how to do this?**

For now, I have only one idea
to deal with the **Multivalue** component (each group is a separate Multivalue component).
But not sure it's a good idea)

Comment: I suggest to read the documentation. There are sample code that is similar to what you are looking.

Comment: Can you please provide some examples? please take a look this screen https://prnt.sc/qybp8p

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if you want to achieve something like this.

```js
const selected_options = [{
    label: "Dark Colours",
    options: [{
        label: "colour 1",
        value: "value1"
      },
      {
        label: "colour 2",
        value: "value2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Light Colours",
    options: [{
        label: "colour 3",
        value: "value3"
      },
      {
        label: "colour 4",
        value: "value4"
      }
    ]
  },
];
```